# What's the difference between 打开 and 开门?

Tags: grammar

How can I tell when to use `打开` and when to use `开门` in Chinese? For example, in the following sentences:

- 这扇门打开了
- 这个书店开门了

Why does the first sentence use `打开` and the latter use `开门`?

Also, is it necessary to use `了` in this sentence?

Comment: Oops. That was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: To summarize the below answers: 打开 = (roughly) to open, 开门 = (roughly) open the door/shop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of the example you posted, 开门 is describing the status of the shop. Like the meaning of 'open' and 'closed' signs you could find in most of stores.

打开 in the context of the example you gave is describing the status of the door or anything could be turned on like window, valve or switch. This sentence should be translated to 'This door is open'.

Because in Chinese a word's meaning may varies according to the context and situation of the sentence. You should remember some combination of noun-adjective or verb-adverb but not just remember the meaning of a single word.

Answer (score 4):

In your examples
The first sentence "这扇门开打了", in English means "The window is opened."
The second sentence "这个书店开门了", in English means "The bookstore is on bussiness."
And, in the first sentence 开打 means open; in the second sentence 开门 means be bussiness.
The 了 is necessary for a normal Chinese sentence.

Answer (score 1):

打開 (verb-complement) is to open. You can open a door, a window, a book, etc. A common usage is 把 something 打開. 
開門 (verb-object) is to open a door.

Comment: Thanks. But why is your Chinese different from mine and others? Does it have the same meaning?

Comment: He used traditional characters

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just started to learn simplified mandarin Chinese a few weeks ago and didn't know anything about the traditional characters.

Comment: I am a "she" :)

Answer (score 0):

打开， 把器皿或盒子的盖子掀开。它的反义词是“关闭”。

To move a cover from closed position. E.g. open a bottle of scotch, open a door.

source: http://baike.baidu.com/view/72184.htm?fr=aladdin

---

开门, 打开房门。也指敞开门户。表示欢迎。

Literary translated as "open the door." Often used as a welcoming gesture. In the case of meaning "business is open," the door does not have to be literally open.

source: http://baike.baidu.com/subview/254067/12526864.htm?fr=aladdin

---

了 [1]放在动词或形容词后，表示动作或变化已经完成：写完了；哭了。

It is necessary here to indicate the action is complete.

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/view/17367.htm

Answer (score 0):

开门 is short for 打开门。打开 means open。

Answer (score -1):

I think the difference is 1 is physical status of the shop and 2 is functional status of the shop.